# nginx doesn't properly route to webapp and omitting path

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, configuration

I am currently configuring a nginx reverse proxy. The docker instance of nextcloud is available on Port `8891`

```
server {
  listen 8888 ssl http2;
  ...

  location /nextcloud/ {
  proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8891/;
 }

}
```

however when I try to navigateto the url, I have the problem, that the stylesheets etc. are not available under `/nextcloud/*` instead they are getting fetched from `/core/*`. [image: omitting path]

Removing the trailing slash from `proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8891;` navigates me to the docker nextcloud webapp however it's trying to fetch the explicit `/nextcloud/` path instead of interpreting it as `/` [image]

How can I archive, that the sources like `server.cs`s is getting fetched from `/nextcloud/`, and basically the whole nextcloud web app is available under `/nextcloud`/?

Answer (score 0):

```
rewrite ^/nextcloud/(.+)$ /$1 break;
```